# How to update all the rows in a specific column in SQLITE3?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    id integer,
    name text
);

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM example;
>> 10

SELECT * FROM example;
    ...>
id     name
--    --------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

if there is a table like the code-block over, and no values in the column "name" as you can see.

I want to update all the values of the column like (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J)

But, it is so inefficient to write this codes.

UPDATE example SET name = "A" where id = 1,

UPDATE example SET name = "B" where id = 2,

.

.

.

UPDATE example SET name = "J" where id = 10,

Is there some way to run these codes in a code like loop or something?

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `CHAR()` ASCII function here:

```sql
UPDATE example
SET name = CHAR(64 + id);
```

Note that 65 is the ASCII character code for `A`.  Once your `id` column exceeds the number of uppercase alphabets, my answer will start assigning characters which are not uppercase letters.  But your question also does not mention what the additional behavior should be.

Comment: but, in case that the names I want to update are like "smith", "mary",,,"jackson"? How can I write it in a statement?

Comment: That's not what your question says, nor what was answered.  For arbitrary names, put them into a table with a FK `id` column.